# Missing elements in Manpages

Tags: bash, manpage

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.
It is really weird, but in every Manpage (also in ksh and sh), there are missing elements such as the program name or flags. I posted also a picture of the incomplete manpage:

[image: picture of the incomplete manpage]

When I use `info` instead of `man`, everything is OK, so there is an error with `man`...

How can I fix it?

Comment: What terminal program are you using? To me it looks as though the terminal does not support the default encoding.

Comment: Looks like the bold formatting isn't working...not sure why yet. What terminal program are you using? Anything changed in it's fonts, your .profile, .bashrc, etc?

Comment: Oh right, the bold formatting! I'm using gnome-Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce that by configuring bold to a black color in gnome-terminal.

Menu: "Edit" -> "Profile Preferences", then tab "Colors"

Is there a check mark on "Bold color"? If yes, disable.